# How slicing works when step is given separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a `list` object which looks as below:

```
lst = [50,34,98,8,10]
```

The output for the statement `print(lst[::][::-1][::-1][::-1][::-1])` is as below:

```
lst = [50,34,98,8,10]
```

Please help me understand how slicing works when `step` is given separately

Comment: I applaud you for the careful naming of `lst`. thank you for not over-writing a builtin method.

Comment: What behavior were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation:

1. You first do `lst[::]` which is just getting the whole list, it processes it to be `lst[::1]` which gives:

   ```
   >>> lst[::1]
   [50, 34, 98, 8, 10]
   >>>
   ```
2. You're then reversing the list times, but 4 is even so it doesn't get reversed at all:

   ```
   >>> lst[::-1]
   [10, 8, 98, 34, 50]
   >>> lst[::-1][::-1]
   [50, 34, 98, 8, 10]
   >>> lst[::-1][::-1][::-1]
   [10, 8, 98, 34, 50]
   >>> lst[::-1][::-1][::-1][::-1]
   [50, 34, 98, 8, 10]
   >>>
   ```